# Mount Qnap NFS Share on Linux OS

Tags: linux, nfs, qnap

I am trying to mount a NFS share from my Qnap to my laptop which runs Manjaro (Arch Linux) but I keep getting access denied by the server and i can't figure out what the problem is!

```
$ sudo mount 10.0.2.6:/backup /mnt/nas/backup
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.0.2.6:/backup
```

Mount points :

```
$ showmount -e 10.0.2.6
Export list for 10.0.2.6:
/backup      
/Web         
/Recordings  
/Public      
/Multimedia  
/Download    
/Containers
```

[image: Qnap folder permissions]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

On QNAP go to Shared Folders and for desired folder Edit Shared Folder Permissions

- choose Select permission type: NFS host access
- Change Access Right change to Read only or No Limit.
- For allowed IP address add * or 192.168.0.* or similar

Hope it helps

Cheers